# Display specific error message of Validation Error message with node js

Tags: node.js

How to display a specific error message from a Validation Error. I already display the error with this line of code `return res.render("register", {error: err.message});` 
 and show this error `ValidationError: User validation failed: email: Email already exists`
But it is showing my column field name 'email' and I don't wanna do that. Below is the whole error and I only want to display this `message: 'Email already exists'` 
Ignore the location D: i removed my file directory

```
    ValidationError: User validation failed: email: Email already exists
    at ValidationError.inspect  
  errors:
   { email:
      { ValidatorError: Email already exists
          at new ValidatorError (D:)
          at validate (D:)
          at D:
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
        message: 'Email already exists',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        properties: [Object],
        kind: 'user defined',
        path: 'email',
        value: 'email@gmail.com',
        reason: undefined,
        [Symbol(mongoose:validatorError)]: true } },
  _message: 'User validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a specific error message of Validation Error you can use `mapped()` function like below.

```
const errors = validationResult(req);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    console.log(errors.mapped().email.msg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create one temp variable and structure your message,

```
let err_msg = err.errors.email.message;
```

which will give: `'Email already exists'`

You can leave `user validation failed message`, since same message may be repeated for all validations.

Comment: When i add `email.message` to the `err.message` it gives me `Cannot read property 'message' of undefined`

Comment: Did try it got undefined.

Comment: try to print err object then get towards your email message that should work :)
console.log(err); or console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
err{
  message: 'er message',
  email:{
  message:' here is the message which you need' 
}
}

Answer (score 0):

To access nested error message do this
`err.errors.email.message`